# How exactly is std::string_view faster than const std::string&?

Tags: c++, string, c++17, string-view

[`std::string_view`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view) has made it to C++17 and it is widely recommended to use it instead of `const std::string&`.

One of the reasons is performance.

Can someone explain how **exactly** `std::string_view` is/will be faster than `const std::string&` when used as a parameter type? (let's assume no copies in the callee are made)

Comment: `std::string_view` is just an abstraction of the (char * begin, char * end) pair.  You use it when making a `std::string` would be an unnecessary copy.

Comment: In my opinion the question is not exactly which one is faster, but when to use them. If I need some manipulation on string and it is not permanent and/or keep the original value, string_view is perfect because I don't need to make a copy of string to it. But if I only need to check something on string using string::find for example, then the reference is better.

Comment: @QuestionC you use it when you don't want your API to restrict to `std::string` (string_view can accept raw arrays, vectors, `std::basic_string<>` with non-default allocators etc. etc. etc. Oh, and other string_views obviously)

Answer (score 352, accepted):

`std::string_view` is faster in a few cases.

First, `std::string const&` requires the data to be in a `std::string`, and not a raw C array, a `char const*` returned by a C API, a `std::vector<char>` produced by some deserialization engine, etc.  The avoided format conversion avoids copying bytes, and (if the string is longer than the SBO¹ for the particular `std::string` implementation) avoids a memory allocation.

```
void foo( std::string_view bob ) {
  std::cout << bob << "\n";
}
int main(int argc, char const*const* argv) {
  foo( "This is a string long enough to avoid the std::string SBO" );
  if (argc > 1)
    foo( argv[1] );
}
```

No allocations are done in the `string_view` case, but there would be if `foo` took a `std::string const&` instead of a `string_view`.

The second really big reason is that it permits working with substrings without a copy.  Suppose you are parsing a 2 gigabyte json string (!)².  If you parse it into `std::string`, each such parse node where they store the name or value of a node *copies* the original data from the 2 gb string to a local  node.

Instead, if you parse it to `std::string_view`s, the nodes *refer* to the original data.  This can save millions of allocations and halve memory requirements during parsing.

The speedup you can get is simply ridiculous.

This is an extreme case, but other "get a substring and work with it" cases can also generate decent speedups with `string_view`.

An important part to the decision is what you lose by using `std::string_view`.

First you lose ownership.  `string_view` is a dumb pointer to someone else's memory.  Tracking that is a headache.  Of course the same is true of a`const&` to a `std::string`.

Second, lose implicit null termination.  And that is about it.  So if the same string will be passed to 3 functions all of which require a null terminator, converting to `std::string` once may be wise.  Thus if your code is known to need a null terminator, and you don't expect strings fed from C-style sourced buffers or the like, maybe take a `std::string const&`.  Otherwise take a `std::string_view`.

If `std::string_view` had a flag that stated if it was null terminated (or something fancier) it would remove even that last reason to use a `std::string const&`.

There is a case where taking a `std::string` with no `const&` is optimal over a `std::string_view`.  If you need to own a copy of the string indefinitely after the call, taking by-value is efficient.  You'll either be in the SBO case (and no allocations, just a few character copies to duplicate it), or you'll be able to *move* the heap-allocated buffer into a local `std::string`.  Having two overloads `std::string&&` and `std::string_view` might be faster, but only marginally, and it would cause modest code bloat (which could cost you all of the speed gains).

---

¹ Small Buffer Optimization

² Actual use case.

Comment: You also lose ownership. Which is only of interest if the string is returned and it *might* have to be anything besides a sub-string of a buffer which is guaranteed to survive long enough. Actually, the loss of ownership is a very two-edged weapon.

Comment: SBO sounds strange. I've always heard SSO (small string optimization)

Comment: @phu Sure; but strings are not the only thing you use the trick on.

Comment: @phuclv SSO is just a specific case of SBO, which stands for _small buffer optimization_. Alternative terms are _small data opt._, _small object opt._, or _small size opt._.

Comment: Couldn't a compiler, theoretically, optimize away the construction of the string in memory, based on the the actual use pattern of a `const std::string&`?

Comment: A `std::string_view` is also often more uniform than a `std::string` when accessing the stored sequence. That also counts for something. Not to mention that a `std::string const&` has an additional indirection compared to a `std::string_view`, with all the costs involved.

Comment: @einpoklum Sure, if its static type is `const std::string` (thus disallowing casting `const` away), or it has all info on how it is used, the compiler should have a good chance of getting it done. The compiler is explicitly allowed to omit allocations by providing the space needed differently as it sees fit.

Comment: As a side note, `char const*const* argv` just shows how far stupidity and ambiguity can go in C++ code...

Comment: @digito what is ambiguous about that?

Comment: @Deduplicator Care providing a simple example of your comment?

Comment: A valid (though bad) hello world program (newlines omitted) to demonstrate: `#include <string> #include <iostream> void f(std::string const& s) { const_cast<std::string&>(s)[0] = 'H'; std::cout << s; } int main() { f("hello world!\n"); }`

Comment: I recommend against this rationale: "and you don't expect strings fed from C-style sourced buffers or the like"

Just assume that the string in a std::string_view will never be null-terminated. Don't try to rationalize where the string originated from before the std::string_view. That's just asking for trouble.

Answer (score 108):

One way that string_view improves performance is that it allows removing prefixes and suffixes easily. Under the hood, string_view can just add the prefix size to a pointer to some string buffer, or subtract the suffix size from the byte counter, this is usually fast. std::string on the other hand has to copy its bytes when you do something like substr (this way you get a new string that owns its buffer, but in many cases you just want to get part of original string without copying). Example:

```
std::string str{"foobar"};
auto bar = str.substr(3);
assert(bar == "bar");
```

With std::string_view:

```
std::string str{"foobar"};
std::string_view bar{str.c_str(), str.size()};
bar.remove_prefix(3);
assert(bar == "bar");
```

#### Update:

I wrote a very simple benchmark to add some real numbers. I used awesome [google benchmark library](https://github.com/google/benchmark). Benchmarked functions are:

```
string remove_prefix(const string &str) {
  return str.substr(3);
}
string_view remove_prefix(string_view str) {
  str.remove_prefix(3);
  return str;
}
static void BM_remove_prefix_string(benchmark::State& state) {                
  std::string example{"asfaghdfgsghasfasg3423rfgasdg"};
  while (state.KeepRunning()) {
    auto res = remove_prefix(example);
    // auto res = remove_prefix(string_view(example)); for string_view
    if (res != "aghdfgsghasfasg3423rfgasdg") {
      throw std::runtime_error("bad op");
    }
  }
}
// BM_remove_prefix_string_view is similar, I skipped it to keep the post short
```

#### Results

(x86_64 linux, gcc 6.2, "`-O3 -DNDEBUG`"):

```
Benchmark                             Time           CPU Iterations
-------------------------------------------------------------------
BM_remove_prefix_string              90 ns         90 ns    7740626
BM_remove_prefix_string_view          6 ns          6 ns  120468514
```

Comment: It's great that you provided an actual benchmark. This really shows what can be gained in relevant use cases.

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar Thanks for the feedback. I also think benchmarks are valuable, sometimes they change everything.

Answer (score 68):

There are 2 main reasons:

- `string_view` is a slice in an existing buffer, it does not require a memory allocation
- `string_view` is passed by value, not by reference

---

The advantages of having a slice are multiple:

- you can use it with `char const*` or `char[]` without allocating a new buffer
- you can take *multiple* slices and subslices into an existing buffer without allocating
- substring is O(1), not O(N)
- ...

Better and *more consistent* performance all over.

---

Passing by value also has advantages over passing by reference, because aliasing.

Specifically, when you have a `std::string const&` parameter, there is no guarantee that the reference string will not be modified. As a result, the compiler must re-fetch the content of the string after each call into an opaque method (pointer to data, length, ...).

On the other hand, when passing a `string_view` by value, the compiler can statically determine that no other code can modify the length and data pointers now on the stack (or in registers). As a result, it can "cache" them across function calls.

Answer (score 43):

One thing it can do is avoid constructing an `std::string` object in the case of an implicit conversion from a null terminated string:

```
void foo(const std::string& s);

...

foo("hello, world!"); // std::string object created, possible dynamic allocation.
char msg[] = "good morning!";
foo(msg); // std::string object created, possible dynamic allocation.
```

Comment: It might be worth saying that `const std::string str{"goodbye!"}; foo(str);` probably *won't* be any faster with string_view than with string&

Comment: Wont `string_view` be slow as it has to copy two pointers as opposed to one pointer in `const string&` ?

Comment: @balki: In theory, maybe a tiny bit slower to pass (though two pointers [or a pointer and a `size_t`] vs. one is pretty trivial). But in exchange, *use* of the `string_view` is faster; to find the `std::string`'s first character, it needs to follow the reference to some non-fixed, possibly non-local location, then follow the pointer to the beginning of the string to find it. With the `string_view`, it can follow the pointer to the beginning of the view directly. In exchange for copying two pointers up front, you remove a level of indirection from *every* use.

Answer (score 15):

`std::string_view` is basically just a wrapper around a `const char*`. And passing `const char*` means that there will be one less pointer in the system in comparison with passing `const string&` (or `const string*`), which implies something like:

```
string* -> char* -> char[]
           (   string    )
```

Clearly for the purpose of passing const arguments the first pointer is superfluous.

*p.s.* One substancial difference between `std::string_view` and `const char*`, nevertheless, is that the string_views are not required to be null-terminated (they have built-in size), and this allows for random in-place splicing of longer strings.

Comment: What's with the downvotes? `std::string_view`s are just fancy `const char*`s, period. GCC implements them like this: `class basic_string_view {const _CharT* _M_str; size_t _M_len;}`

Comment: just get to 65K rep (from your current 65) and this would be the accepted answer (waves to the cargo-cult crowds) :)

Comment: @mlvljr Nobody passes `std::string const*`. And that diagram is unintelligible. @ n.caillou: Your own comment is already more accurate than the answer. That makes `string_view` more than "fancy `char const*`" - it's really quite obvious.

Comment: @sehe I could be that nobody, no problemo (i.e. passing a pointer (or reference) to a const string, why not?) :)

Comment: @sehe You do understand that from an optimization or execution perspective, `std::string const*` and `std::string const&` are the same, don't you?

Comment: @n.caillou: From a convenience and programmer safety perspective, the ability of a `const` reference to perform implicit keep-alive duties for temporaries (which no pointer does), and prevent (non-pathological) passing of nullptrs is a major part of why no one uses `std::string const*`.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Obviously. But the question is about execution speed, so it's important to understand that references are essentially pointers with safer semantics

Comment: No they are not. You have to dereference pointer to reach out data but no need for that for references. So execution speed is not the same between pointers and references.

Comment: @ArdahanKisbet ...because the compiler dereferences the reference for you