# Is a for-loop or iterator a faster way to traverse a string?

Tags: c++, string, performance, c++11

I have a string.

```
std::string strLine;
```

I can traverse the string chars using a `if` loop

```
for (int i = 0; strLine[i]; i++)
```

Another way i can do is using string iterator

```
string::iterator it;
for (it = strLine.begin(); it < strLine.end(); it++)
```

Which is a faster and flexible way to iterate ?

Comment: This question already has an answer here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2113216/which-is-more-efficient-a-for-each-loop-or-an-iterator

Comment: I don't think `std::string` is guaranteed to be null terminated so your for loop might not work. You should use `for(int i = 0; i < strLine.size(); ++i)` EDIT: strLine is null terminated since c++11

Comment: @Sdp that's a Jave question.

Comment: @BradyDean Null termination is guaranteed since C++11.

Comment: @eerorika Ah ok, I tried to verify that before I posted but I missed it. It would make sense because of `c_str`.

Comment: @BradyDean Prior to C++11, calling `c_str` was guaranteed to return pointer to null terminated string, but there was no guarantees otherwise.

Comment: @eerorika So did the pre-c++11 implementations just stick a null at the end when `c_str` was called? I'd imagine it would be easier just to implement it with a c string anyways

Comment: @BradyDean libstdc++ did. I don't know if they were the only one. It's marginally cheaper to only do it on call to `c_str` instead of on every construction even when the `c_str` was never called I guess.

Comment: If you care about performance avoid strings

Comment: @user997112 No, use strings I say. For performance critical stuff we nowadays got stringview and whatnot.

Comment: @nada What is stringview and whatnot, please? `<string_view>`?

Comment: @faressalem Yes, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40127965/4850111) is a relevant SO question discussing its performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this code printing a string `This is a string!`:
[LIVE](https://rextester.com/NBIMBC4322)

```
    cpu_time_start = clock();
    real_time_start = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    for (auto i = 0u; i < strLine.size(); ++i)
        cout << strLine[i];
    cout << endl;

    cpu_time_end = clock();
    real_time_end = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    cout << "index-based loop CPU time: " << 1000.0 * (cpu_time_end-cpu_time_start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << " ms\n"
         << "index-based loop real time: "<< chrono::duration<double, milli>(real_time_end-real_time_start).count() << " ms\n";

    //---------------------------------------------------------------------

    // get start time, same as above 
    for (auto i = strLine.begin(); i != strLine.end(); ++i)
        cout << *i;
    cout << endl;
    // get end time and print 

    //---------------------------------------------------------------------

    // get start time, same as above
    for (auto &c: strLine)
        cout << c;
    cout << endl;
    // get end time and print
```

---

**EDIT :**

Thanks to @cigien, He pointed out to a more accurate way for benchmarking by warming up, It seems that they are a little bit close to each other in performance in terms of the time of execution, and if you change the order of loops in the code, it appears that any could be slightly faster than the other, I think that's due to caching, but yet I don't think that the compiler will produce the same code for them. You can warm up by just printing out the string first before printing by iteration. And maybe a more accurate way to compare them is to test each loop in one program on its own.

This is the output when compiled with `g++ -Wall -std=c++17 -O2`.

```
warming up for tests ...
This is a string!
warmed up for tests ...
This is a string!
index-based loop CPU time: 0.008 ms
index-based loop real time: 0.005986 ms
This is a string!
iterator-based loop CPU time: 0.004 ms
iterator-based loop real time: 0.003417 ms
This is a string!
range-for based loop CPU time: 0.003 ms
range-for based loop real time: 0.002755 ms
```

I'll leave this part of the **OLD ANSWER** for people to know what happened:

**OLD OUTPUT !**

```
This is a string!
index-based loop CPU time: 0.054 ms
index-based loop real time: 0.054416 ms
This is a string!
iterator-based loop CPU time: 0.005 ms
iterator-based loop real time: 0.004291 ms
This is a string!
range-for based loop CPU time: 0.004 ms
range-for based loop real time: 0.004308 ms
```

It looks that the `range-for loop` and the `iterator-based loop` are very close in performance in terms of the time of execution and both execute about `10x` faster than the `index-based loop`. Try larger length strings for more accurate results and run it many times and take the average.

You could also try compiling it on [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/), I don't think the same code will be generated.

Answer (score 4):

There are some issues with the example loops you've shown. Here's some common ways of iterating over a string:

```
// index based loop
for (auto i = 0u; i < strLine.size(); ++i)
  cout << strLine[i];

// iterator based loop
for (auto i = strLine.begin(); i != strLine.end(); ++i)
  cout << *i;

// range-for loop
for (auto &c: s)
  cout << c;
```

All these versions have the same performance, since the compiler will generate basically the same code for all of them.

Inspired by @farassalem's answer with a benchmark, I added the following lines before running the same tests:

```
cout << "warming up for tests ...\n";
cout << strLine << endl;
cout << "warmed up for tests ...\n";
```

and you get essentially the same performance for all 3 versions:

```
warming up for tests ...
This is a string!
warmed up for tests ...
This is a string!
index-based loop CPU time: 0.003 ms
index-based loop real time: 0.003264 ms
This is a string!
iterator-based loop CPU time: 0.003 ms
iterator-based loop real time: 0.003131 ms
This is a string!
range-for based loop CPU time: 0.002 ms
range-for based loop real time: 0.002728 ms
```

You should still pay close attention to *how* you benchmark before taking the results too seriously.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out :D Can you please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61510370/11024053) question?

Answer (score 0):

Did a replication test, source code: https://gist.github.com/thepiper/7d510b080fae8596e7c281a0af7b89f2

### Results

TL;DR confirmed that it most likely doesn't matter.

#### Data

gcc flags: `c++17 O3`

```
Running 1000 iterations for string of length 10000...
range-for based loop real time AVERAGE: 2.18977 ms
iterator based loop real time AVERAGE: 2.20931 ms
index based loop real time AVERAGE: 2.17943 ms
```

gcc flags: `c++17 O2`

```
Running 1000 iterations for string of length 10000...
range-for based loop real time AVERAGE: 2.0172 ms
iterator based loop real time AVERAGE: 2.02376 ms
index based loop real time AVERAGE: 2.02123 ms
```

gcc flags: `c++17 O`

```
Running 1000 iterations for string of length 10000...
range-for based loop real time AVERAGE: 2.15027 ms
iterator based loop real time AVERAGE: 2.15071 ms
index based loop real time AVERAGE: 2.15947 ms
```

gcc flags: `c++11 O3`

```
Running 1000 iterations for string of length 10000...
range-for based loop real time AVERAGE: 2.01957 ms
iterator based loop real time AVERAGE: 2.02568 ms
index based loop real time AVERAGE: 2.02657 ms
```

gcc flags: `c++11 O2`

```
Running 1000 iterations for string of length 10000...
range-for based loop real time AVERAGE: 2.03002 ms
iterator based loop real time AVERAGE: 2.02997 ms
index based loop real time AVERAGE: 2.03698 ms
```

gcc flags: `c++11 O`

```
Running 1000 iterations for string of length 10000...
range-for based loop real time AVERAGE: 2.03777 ms
iterator based loop real time AVERAGE: 2.03003 ms
index based loop real time AVERAGE: 2.04184 ms
```

### Test Parameters

- string length of `10021`
- `1000` iterations

### Test procedure:

Common compiler flags: `g++ -g -Wall`

Every iteration, the three functions under test (range, iterator, and index loops) are ran on the test string `strLine` in a new random order.

Runtime is logged for each, and a cumulative time is kept. Taking a cumulative average has been tried, but it accumulates precision errors rapidly and vastly under reports, so the average is taken at the end.

After the total number of iterations are complete, average is taken.

CPU time is omitted as my `std::clock()` returns full milliseconds, making the measurement uninformative.